# how to add a radio button in every row in datatable inside a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, bootstrap-modal

I have a form and in that form is a button that triggers a modal to appear. And inside my modal is datatable. I used ajax to fill in each row. Now I want to add a column for radio button and get its value and pass it to a parent window. How am I going to make it?

```js
<script>
var table;
$('#list_user').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
 // alert("hi");
  
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
   
    
  $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo site_url('Account/getAllUsers')?>",
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function(result){
       var modal=$(this);
        
  
       // var response = $.parseJSON(result.contents);

          //clear the table to remove cloned rows
          
         if (table) table.clear();

         //reinitialise the dataTable   
         table = $('#records_table').DataTable({
           destroy: true,
           bLengthChange: false,
           // paging: true
            
            dom: 'frtp'
         });
        $('#records_table').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
          $('#list_user').modal('hide')
     });

         $.each(result, function(i, item) {
           console.log("inserting", item);
           table.row.add([
             item.user_id,
             item.user_name
             
           ]).draw();
         });
        
      }
                   
  });
  
   
  
  
  
});

</script>
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="modal fade" id="list_user" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="modal-header"> 
              <button class="btn btn-primary close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 id="hdrmsg">List of Users</h4> 
            </div> 
            <div class="modal-body"> 
              <div class="welll"> 
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-responsive" id="records_table">
       <thead class="header">
            <tr class="well">
            <th>ID #</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody style="overflow: scroll">
          
       </tbody>
    </table> 
              
            </div>  
          </div> 

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just include a `<input type=radio" ...` etc in your `table.row.add([` ..?

Comment: @davidkonrad thanks for taking the time to answer, it worked, I have solved it..